# $\{\cos({2}^{n}x)\}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, analysis

I know  that if $\{\cos(nx)\}$ is convergent to a finite limit, then $\frac{x}{2\pi}\in\mathbb Z$. Now if $\{\cos(2^nx)\}$ convergent to a finite limit, could we find $x$ and how?

Comment: The second is a subsequence of the first.

Comment: I would say that $\frac{x}{2\pi}\in \mathbb{Z}$ for your first case. $\cos(n\pi)$ does not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Note that $\cos(2 x) = f(\cos x)$ where $f(t) = 2 t^2 - 1$.
Thus $\cos(2^n x) = f^n(\cos x)$ (where $f^n$ means $f$ iterated $n$ times).

If $\cos(2^n x) \to L$ as $n \to \infty$, then $L$ must be a fixed point of $f$, namely $-1/2$ or $1$.  However, these are unstable fixed points since $f'(-1/2) = -2$ and $f'(1) = 4$, and both of these have absolute value $> 1$.  Therefore the only way to have $f^n(t) \to L$ is that $f^m(t) = L$ for some $m$.

We conclude that the only possible $x$ are of the form $2^{-m} k \pi/3$ for some integers $m$ and $k$.
If $k$ is divisible by $3$, $\cos(2^n x) \to 1$, while if $k$ is not divisible by $3$, $\cos(2^n x) \to -1/2$.

Comment: What a nice proof! Thank you!